# identify the beginning year of the longest valid series

Tags: excel

I need to return the beginning year of the longest valid series of data.  I have the below data:

```
     1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007
ID_A 0    0    1    2    3    0    1    2    3    4    5    0    1
```

It's straightforward to identify the ending year of the longest non-zero series, using INDEX (=2005).  What I am having problem is to return the beginning year of the longest non-zero series, which is 2001.  How can I achieve it?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your "straighforward" function. What are you actually using? Naming 2005 seems like a literal, not something derived by a formula. Please edit your question and post the formula you use to arrive at that. Also, please write some words that explain the logic to identify the beginning year of the longest non-zero series. It may be perfectly clear to you, but it is not for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the formula you are using and describing as straightforward is something like this:

```
=INDEX(B1:N1,,MATCH(MAX(B2:N2),B2:N2,0))
```

[image]

That formula doesn't check for the proper sequencing on the values on the second row, so I'll assume all the series are valid when suggesting the formula for the beginning year:

```
=INDEX(B1:N1,,MATCH(MAX(B2:N2),B2:N2,0)-MAX(B2:N2)+1)
```

The above basically gets the column number of the ending year used previously, and subtracts the last value in the series to get the beginning year.

[image]

If the validity of a series has to be checked, then the first formula will not work (and the second one neither). I don't think it would be straight forward enough so that a single formula would suffice, but it should definitely be possible with a helper row that identifies valid series (simple subtraction between the value of a series and the next value).

Answer (score 0):

Jerry [beat me to the punch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887255). I had partially written an answer and then had to go away for a while; I feel this still adds something (namely, a longer explanation), but because my formula is the same as his and because his is, in my opinion, complete and correct, I'm making this community wiki.

---

So, we can find the length of the longest non-zero series (`5`) with the `MAX` function:

`=MAX(B2:N2)`

We can then use that inside the `MATCH` function to find the end of that series in the ID_A row (`11` here, as we're counting from `1` at the 1995 column):

`=MATCH( MAX(B2:N2) ,B2:N2,0)`

To find the ending year, use all of that inside `INDEX` to return, in this case, the 11th year:

`=INDEX(B1:N1,, MATCH(MAX(B2:N2),B2:N2,0) )`

To find the starting year, use 'INDEX' in the same way, but count backwards 5—no, 5 minus 1—places:

`=INDEX(B1:N1,1,MATCH(MAX(B2:N2),B2:N2,0) -MAX(B2:N2)+1 )`